# Spark executor not increasing in jdbc source

Tags: apache-spark

While trying to read large oracle table with spark jdbc connection only one executor is invoking even dynamica allocation is enabled and job is stuck there

I am running a spark application to read from two oracle tables -

1) For small table where I am running the spark submit application with dynamic resource allocation it's creating 15 executors and completing within 2 minutes for 100 records

2) For large table also using same configuration but job is getting executed for 4 hours only on single executor , it's not increasing

numpartitions is 10 but still using one executor

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --driver-cores 2 --driver-memory 2G --jars /tmp/ojdbc8.jar --master yarn /tmp/vol_1.py location --executor-memory 12G  --executor-cores 5
```

Is this a spark limitation ? Is the read always happen on single executor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not explicitly specified, Spark SQL will not partition any data and all rows are processed by a single executor. Set partition column(partitionColumn must be a numeric, date, or timestamp column), lower bound and upper bound along with num partitions.
[Check this link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html)

Comment: thanks but it doesn't seem an elegant solution because without reading the data it's impossible to get the upper and lower bound . sqoop does the same thing and doesn't require any limits